# Why are the IMAP functions in PHP so horribly slow?

Tags: php, imap, php-imap

Why are the IMAP functions in PHP so horribly slow? And are there any recommended workarounds? I've got a small bit of PHP running on a private server that I have set up to poll a couple of different Gmail inboxes and aggregate the new messages for me. It's always been slow -- checking four mailboxes could take several seconds to complete. More recently for reasons I can't explain, it's mostly stopped working altogether. The server just times out on the first request despite the credentials still being valid.

In searching for solutions to this problem, I came across [this "bug report"](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=33702) which was quickly shoved under the table. But it seems I'm not the only one who's noticed the IMAP library in PHP is almost unusably slow.

Has anyone else encountered this problems and come up with any techniques for accessing IMAP mailboxes in reasonable amounts of time? (Several seconds is quite unreasonable!)

Here's what I'm doing, essentially:

```
if ($mbox = imap_open('{imap.gmail.com:993/imap/ssl}INBOX', $users[$i], $passwords[$i])) {

    $inbox = imap_check($mbox);
    $total = (int) $inbox->Nmsgs;

    if ($total > 0 && ($emails = imap_fetch_overview($mbox, "1:{$total}"))) {
        foreach ($emails as $email) {
            $messages[] = array(
                'from' => $email->from,
                'subj' => $email->subject,
                'date' => strtotime($email->date),
                'read' => $email->seen
            );
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What IMAP operations are you performing?

Comment: In my experience (many years) Gmail's weird IMAP adaptation has always been slow for all clients.  I find PHP's IMAP to work fine for normal, well-behaved IMAP though.

Comment: @duskwuff I added some code to the question. I'm using three functions per mailbox: imap_open, imap_check, and imap_fetch_overview.

Comment: I am not sure if this happens because of the PHPs IMAP interface but most likely my mind goes to `free email account` and `QOS (quality of service)` so ...

Comment: How many messages are in your inbox? 10? 10,000?

Comment: It doesn't surprise me that this takes a while to run. I use the Mutt text email client with Gmail as my primary mail thing and it typically takes 2-5 seconds to complete the SSL negotiation, login, and display inbox (empty or nearly empty). Changing mailboxes is very slow in gmail's IMAP approximation too.

Comment: @duskwuff anywhere between 5 and 20 messages. So not a lot!

Comment: Have you benchmarked other clients to be sure it is a problem with PHP? If not, this is little more than a rant.

Comment: What does imap_check do under the hood?  It seems unnecessary and may or may not add several round trips to get its information.

Comment: @vascowhite I'll try to whip something up in Java after work and will let you know what I find. I had initially assumed this was a problem unique to PHP but didn't consider that maybe Gmail's protocol is the real culprit as others have speculated.

Comment: @SoaperGEM I’d be interested to see the results of that. Would it be possible for you to edit the result into your question and then reply to me here so I get to see them? I’d happily remove my down vote then 